# Cannot be send mail through jmeter webdriver sampler

Tags: jmeter

I tried to send mail through jmeter in webdriver sampler but it throw me below error but code is work on eclipse java correctly.
Code-

```
    final String username = "xyz@abc.com";  // like yourname@outlook.com
    final String password = "ABC@123";   // password here


    Properties props = new Properties();
    props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
    props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
    props.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp-mail.outlook.com");
    props.put("mail.smtp.port", "587");

    Session session = Session.getInstance(props,
      new javax.mail.Authenticator() {
     //   @Override
         PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
            return new PasswordAuthentication(username, password);
        }
      });
    session.setDebug(true);

    try {

        Message message = new MimeMessage(session);
        message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(username));
        message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO,
            InternetAddress.parse("PQS@abc.com"));   // like inzi769@gmail.com
        message.setSubject("Test");
        message.setText("HI you have done sending mail with outlook");


             Transport.send(message);

            WDS.log.info("Done");

    }
```

Error-
Encountered "( props , new javax . mail . Authenticator ( ) { PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication ("

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to choose `groovy` from the Language drop-down

[image]

when you choose `java` it is not real Java, but [Beanshell](http://www.beanshell.org/) which has slightly different syntax and in general [is not recommended for using since JMeter 3.1](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#bsh_scripting)

---

Any reason for not using [SMTP Sampler](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#SMTP_Sampler) for sending the email? It will be much faster and easier. Check out [Load Testing Your Email Server: How to Send and Receive E-mails with JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/load-testing-your-email-server-how-send-and-receive-e-mails-jmeter) article for comprehensive information on configuration and usage.

Comment: Thanks sir Its work but it show me below error but code work correctly and I am not using SMTP sampler because I want to send report which generated using script through mail.

Comment: Error Response code: 500
Response message: unknown protocol: data

Comment: You can store the report into JMeter Variables as `WDS.vars.put('report', your_report_here)` and refer the generated variable as **${report}** in the SMTP Sampler. Check out [The WebDriver Sampler: Your Top 10 Questions Answered](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/webdriver-sampler-your-top-10-questions-answered) article for more WebDriver Sampler tips and tricks